# What is the summation of squared deviation wrt $\ell_2$-norm from vector mean in terms of individual deferences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, machine-learning

Let $\{\textbf{y}_t\}_{t=1}^T$ is a vector sequence. Summation of squared deviation wrt $\ell_2$-norm from vector mean of $\frac{1}{T}\sum \limits_{t=1}^{T}\textbf{y}_t$ is
$$
\sum \limits_{t=1}^{T} \|\textbf{y}_t-\frac{1}{T}\sum \limits_{j=1}^{T}\textbf{y}_j \|_2^2
$$

What is the equivalent sum in terms of $\sum \limits_{t=1}^{T} \sum \limits_{j=1}^{T} \|\textbf{y}_t-\textbf{y}_j \|_2^2$. Is the following true?
$$
\sum \limits_{t=1}^{T} \|\textbf{y}_t-\frac{1}{T}\sum \limits_{j=1}^{T}\textbf{y}_j \|_2^2=\frac{1}{2T}\sum \limits_{t=1}^{T} \sum \limits_{j=1}^{T} \|\textbf{y}_t-\textbf{y}_j \|_2^2
$$
The above formula is from the following paper (page 3):
[http://proceedings.mlr.press/v23/chiang12/chiang12.pdf]

In the following picture from the paper, $\{\textbf{y}_t\}_{t=1}^T$ can be thought of as $\{\nabla f_t(x_t)\}_{t=1}^T$.
[image]

Comment: I think there must be extra hypothesis on the vectors. The formula you have quoted doesn't seem to hold for 1-dimensional case with $T=2$ and  $x_1+x_2=0$. Is it given that $\sum ||y_k||^{2}=\sum||x_k||^{2}$?

Comment: The question statement was not correct. The sum evaluate deviations from mean of the sequence itself.